# replace row data in pandas based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample dataframe

```
     name
 0   Newyork
 1   Los Angeles
 2   Ohio
 3   Washington DC
 4   Kentucky
```

Also I've a second dataframe

```
      name      ratio
 0   Newyork     1:2
 1   Kentucky    3:7
 2   Florida     1:5
 3   SF          2:9
```

How can I replace the data of `name` column in the `df2` with `not available`, if the name is present in `df1`?

Desired result:

```
     name           ratio
 0   Not Available   1:2
 1   Not Available   3:7
 2   Florida         1:5
 3   SF              2:9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df2['name'] = np.where(df2['name'].isin(df1['name']), 'Not Available', df2['name'])
```